# First and follow in the following grammar

Tags: parsing, recursion, compiler-construction, grammar

The following grammar is given:-

```
E->E+T|T 
T->T*F|F 
F->id
```

I have tried to find the first and follow. Can anyone verify it whether its correct???

```
First(E)={id}
First(T)={id}
First(F)={id}
Follow(E)={+,id}
Follow(T)={+}
Follow(F)={id,*}
```

Comment: What is an example of a derivation in which an `F` is followed by an `id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIRST sets are correct,

```
FOLLOW(A) of non-terminal A is the set of terminal symbols that can follow in the   
derivation sequence
```

FOLLOW(E), check where it is there in the right-hand side of production. It is there in

```
    E->E+T
```

what follows E when we consider this production for derivation is '+' and '$'(End of Input) is also added to the follow of start symbol

```
   FOLLOW(E) ={+,$}
```

FOLLOW(T), it is there in right-hand side of three productions

```
   E-> E+T   E->T  T->T*F
   FOLLOW(T)={*} U FOLLOW(E)={*,+,$}
```

FOLLOW(F), it is there in right-hand side of two productions

```
   T->T*F  T->F
   FOLLOW(F)=FOLLOW(T)={*,+,$}
```

If you are doing this exercise for computing LL(1) parsing table then first eliminate left recursion and proceed.